# How to create custom login page

Tags: wordpress

I have created a site in wordpress and in the flamingo theme there is no login page.

So i want to create a login page for the theme.

Can anyone suggest how to create custom login page in wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create a custom Login Form, to make it little bit easy create a [custom template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template)
Then you have to make a login form into your template.
Now use [wp_signon()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) to make the user login, take a look on this example:

```
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = 'example';
$creds['user_password'] = 'plaintextpw';
$creds['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
if ( is_wp_error($user) )
    echo $user->get_error_message();
```

Comment: @user3110084 you already selected the answer, but anyway nice to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize the current wordpress login page (usually wp-login.php) you should take a look at [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org) for [Customizing the Login Form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form).

Or if you want to create a separate login page for your theme, I suggest you to use [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) to do this.

This plugin themes the WordPress login, registration and forgot password pages according to your current theme. It creates a page to use in place of **wp-login.php**, using a page template from your theme. Also includes a widget for sidebar login.

#### Plugin Features

- Your registration, log in, and password recovery pages will all match the rest of your website
- Includes a customizable widget to login anywhere from your blog
- Redirect users upon log in and log out based upon their role
- Show gravatar to users who are logged in
- Assign custom links to users who are logged in based on their role
- Customize user emails for registration and/or password recovery
- Send user emails in HTML format
- Allow users to set their own password upon registration
- Require users to be approved or confirm e-mail address upon registration
- Theme user profiles

Answer (score 0):

you can use a login plugin or you can create a template where you can write all php code for login functionality.ex:
use wp_signon() function
or use $_REQUEST global variable and perform a select query